# TYPO3 typeNum arguments

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-extensions

I want to make a link from a template to a pageType, made for iCal download:

```
<f:link.action pageType="730" arguments="{event: event}" target="_blank" title="bla">iCal Download</f:link.action>
```

In typoscript

```
tx_myext_icalendar = PAGE

tx_myext_icalendar {
typeNum = 730

config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    xhtml_cleaning = none
    admPanel = 0
    metaCharset = utf-8
    additionalHeaders = Content-Type:text/calendar;charset=utf-8
    disablePrefixComment = 1
}

10 = USER
10 {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    vendorName = Me
    extensionName = SiteMe
    pluginName = Events
    switchableControllerActions {
        Icalevent {
            1 = iCalendar
        }
    }
}
}
```

In my iCalendarAction in the IcalleventController I never receive the arguments. No matter what I type there, not by parameter, neither by $this->request->getArguments()

I guess I need to adjust the typoscript. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Can you add information about your PluginNames? Is the PluginName of the plugin rendering the link the same as it is in your TypoScript snippet?

Comment: What kind of arguments are you looking for? `Action` arguments or arguments like `$_GET` and `$_POST`?

Comment: Looking at your TS code your link in markup should look like `...&type=730&tx_siteme_events[controller]=Icalevent&tx_siteme_events[action]=iCalendar&tx_siteme_events[event]=...`. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. Indeed the extensionname, pluginname, action, controller were needed in the link.action.

The thing is that the config extension which holds this, uses a custom extension that defines things like custom content elements. (I did not create this, so I got confused by it). Therefore the generated link was not the same (for extensionname, pluginname, action and controller) as defined in the pagetype. By explicitly defining them in the html template (link action), any argument is now received in the ical template.